# Weird hex numbers in BMP file

Tags: binary, pixel, bmp, terminator

I have a weird thing in BMP GRAPHICS files.

I create them with FULLSHOT 9 (screen capture software) (just mouse click+drag a rectangle on the screen and save as .bmp FILE).

When i watch the file in the binary editor, i can see a pixel being use for a loooong time as expected.

So you see something like this:

(editor shows 8 hex numbers per row)(Pixel = 3 hex numbers like "ED ED ED")

0x00002f0   <---- some offset from start of file (long past header part of bmp file, after which i only expect a long sequence of pixels, not some extra information)

```
ED  ED  ED  ED  ED  ED  ED  ED
ED  ED  ED  ED  ED  ED  ED  ED
ED  ED  ED  ED  ED  ED  ED  ED
ED  ED  ED  ED  ED  ED  ED  ED
```

But then suddenly you see a block of regular (like Pixel = 3 hex numbers) but not repeating numbers

```
EF  EF  EF
F0  F0  F0
F2  F2  F2
F3  F3  F3
F5  F5  F5
F7  F7  F7
F8  F8  F8
FA  FA  FA
FB  FB  FB
FD  FD  FD
```

(i made the newline after each group of 3 for clarity....
the binary editor shows 8 hex numbers in a row)

i suspect these are not actual pixels but some "information"
Then often you see a weird 0 alone.

```
00  <----i suspect a terminator of some sort.
```

then the "information" part continues...

```
but now (most of the time) in reverse order
FD  FD  FD
FB  FB  FB
FA  FA  FA ..etc
```

and stops, and a new looooong repetition of pixels.

```
DC  DC  DC  DC  DC  DC  DC  DC  
DC  DC  DC  DC  DC  DC  DC  DC  
DC  DC  DC  DC  DC  DC  DC  DC  
DC  DC  DC  DC  DC  DC  DC  DC  
DC  DC  DC  DC  DC  DC  DC  DC
```

PROBLEM:
These blocks of "information" disturb me from collecting all the actual pixels.
If i knew what they were, i could tell the program to skip them.

QUESTION 1:
What could the meaning of this "information" part be?

QUESTION 2: 
Is the zero really a terminator?

PS
I have measured the difference between the reoccurring zero's and it usually is a multiple of "with of the bitmap" in different .bmp files i created and examined.

Answer (score 0):

All the information you need is at [Wikipedia on the BMP Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format).

> 0x00002f0 <---- some offset from start of file (long past header part of bmp file, after which i only expect a long sequence of pixels, not some extra information)

You don't mention at what position you find this value, but that is probably the start of the raw pixel data:

> **Bitmap File Header**
>
> ..
>
> 000Ah 4 bytes the offset, i.e. starting address, of the byte where the bitmap image data (pixel array) can be found.

Q1. The "information" is, from the looks of it, just a palette. It is not *required* for a true color bitmap to contain an explicit palette, but then again it *may* have one. Theoretically, this would be an optimized 8-bit palette for the same image, but I wouldn't count on it. The part you show is a simple list of grays.

Q2. Those zeroes may be DWORD line padding. They occur at "multiples of bitmap width", because each *line* in your image occupies, in fact, a "multiple of the bitmap width" bytes -- 3 times for RGB, 4 times for RGBA. Only at the end of the line, zeroes are inserted to make sure the *next* line starts at a DWORD boundary.